# OnClickListener for many views

Tags: android, imageview

I have done some onclick listeners before in earlier projects but i have have never done like 100-200 onclicks. The idea is a horizontal scroll that AddImagViews to it if a variable is == somethin and if you click the imageview the imageview will setText to an TextView.

I have done the set imageview part but is there any easier way then creating like 100 different onclick for each imageview. Sorry if this was bad explained and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, have your Activity implemenent OnClickListener something like:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.splash_startScan:
            // do something
            break;
        case R.id.splash_startReview:
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
```

then for each button do

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic onClick event that reacts to the view that is passed to it. You can use a decision statement (like an if statement) to determine the button, but if all you need is the text from the button you can get that generically by casting the view back into a button and getting its text.

```
Button button = (Button)v;
button.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Sorry, replace Button with ImageView and things should behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to create a class that implements onClickListener and has a constructor that passes in what you need and then just set the listener to a new instance of that object with the right parameters.